# How to enable Font Family, Font Size, Font Colour, and Justification?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed Drupal 10.0.08. on my Windows 10 PC .It is running on XAMPP framework locally.

When I want to create content (either a *Basic Page* or an *Article* node) using CKeditor 5 on Drupal 10.0.8, the menu looks like in the screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I **have enabled the full HTML option** at the bottom.

I am not able to find any options for:

- The text font
- Justification options (*right*, *left*, *center*, *justified*)
- Text size

How do I enable them?

Do I have to install other modules to activate those options?

Answer (score 3):

1. Browse to /admin/config/content/formats.
2. Click "configure" on the
   text format you wish to change.
3. Drag desired toolbar buttons into
   place.

Buttons not seen there require contributed modules.

Comment: thanks,I cannot find font buttons like Ariel Courier etc

Comment: Asking for modules to suggest is against the site rules. I’ve answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

"there is a plugin for that". but it's minimally supported and is not covered by the security police (as of 2023/05). It looks as if another plugin is moving to implement this, too - https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton/issues/3291717

However, you can achieve something similar with the 'styles' dropdown

- add it to the toolbar of your text format in the admin
- add classes there that reflect your style, like `span.arial|Arial`
- in your themes css, add `span.arial { font-family:arial }`

Optionally, in your theme's `ckeditor5-stylesheets` (google that), add the same